# How to round the hover information when using ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

How to round the hover information when using `ggplotly`? In the following example, I created a scatter plot with hover information. I would like to round the numbers in that hover information to integer without changing the actual values.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = qsec)) +
  geom_point()

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `text` aesthetic to do a custom tooltip:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, 
            aes(x = wt, y = qsec, 
                text = paste0("wt: ", round(wt), "</br></br>qsec: ", round(qsec)))) +
  geom_point()

ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```